# How to configure apollo cache to uniquely identify a child elements based on their parent primary key

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

What is the proper way to configure apollo's cache normalization for a child array fields that do not have an ID of their own but are unique in the structure of their parent?

Let's say we have the following schema:

```
type Query {
  clients: [Client!]!
}

type Client {
  clientId: ID
  name: String!
  events: [Events!]!
}

type Events {
  month: String!
  year: Int!
  day: Int!
  clients: [Client!]!
}
```

At first I thought I can use multiple `keyFields` to achieve a unique identifier like this:

```js
const createCache = () => new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Event: {
      keyFields: ['year', 'month', 'name'],
    },
  },
});
```

*There would never be more than 1 event per day so it's safe to say that the event is unique for a client based on date*

But the created cache entries lack a `clientId` (in the cache key) so 2 events that are on the same date but for different clients cannot be distinguished

Is there a proper way to configure `typePolicies` for this relationship?

For example the key field can be set to use a [subfield](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#generating-unique-identifiers):

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Book: {
      keyFields: ["title", "author", ["name"]],
    },
  },
});
```

> The Book type above uses a subfield as part of its primary key. The ["name"] item indicates that the name field of the previous field in the array (author) is part of the primary key. The Book's author field must be an object that includes a name field for this to be valid.

In my case I'd like to use a parent field as part of the primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't add a unique event id, then the fallback is to [disable normalization](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#disabling-normalization):

> Objects that are not normalized are instead embedded within their parent object in the cache. You can't access these objects directly, but you can access them via their parent.

To do this you set `keyFields` to `false`:

```
const createCache = () => new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Event: {
      keyFields: false
    },
  },
});
```

Essentially each `Event` object will be stored in the cache under its parent `Client` object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this! The schema is simplified for a general solution for this problem - relying on parent field for identification. The relationship is actually one to many the `clients` in the event don't have to have the event added to their `events` as far as they are concerned it doesn't exist. Each event can be distinguished uniquely by combining the `clientId` of the parent and `month`, `day`, `year` fields. The question is: is there any way to configure this?

Comment: Disabling normalization seems to be the way to go in this case (I would prefer to add ID but let's imagine it's impossible). Even with IDs the cache will fill with many events anyway as they are supposed to be unique per client - no 2 clients would ever share an event with the same ID.

Comment: Can you edit out the "backend" part of your answer. You can say something like "If you can't have an ID added to your TYPE then you can disable normalization ... code ..." and I'll flag it as accepted.